# How to call JS array item / Read console log return

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, console.log, filestack

I am trying to narrow down a selection from an object* in my console log. My code is simply:

```
console.log(x)
```

and what is being returned is as follows:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9maNG.png)

Referencing the example image, if I wanted to call "0.filename" how would I go about navigating this returned structure.

*Apologies if object is the wrong term for what is being returned.

Comment: So you basically want to get a past console.log and store it in a variable?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what variable I need but I want to console.log for now. If I wanted my console to read: "image/jpeg", what would I have to call in the console.log(); I am confused on if I am looking at an array or an object... I tried (x.filesUploaded[0][3]);) but it just returned 'undefined' instead of the string

Comment: For your console to say `image/jpeg`, type `console.log("image/jpeg")`

Comment: Revised my original comment, sorry for the miscommunication

Comment: Oh you just wanted to know how to access the certain object value... well the answer below says how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your object x have many attribute and an array filesUploaded you must use:
`console.log(x.filesUploaded[0].filename)`
because filesUploaded is an array so if you want to show all filename you must use loop for it.